# Partition of number $N$ such that smallest number in each partition is not less than $K$

Tags: combinatorics

For a given $N$ and $K$, we need  to compute the number of partitions of $N$ such that the smallest number in each partition is not less than $K$.How can this can be accomplished using combinatorics ?

Comment: One approach would be to specify the number of parts $r$ to be used (at least one part, at most $\lfloor N/K \rfloor$), then work out the partitions of $N-rK$ with at most $r$ parts for each case.

Comment: In a specific case you could use generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function for this kind of partition is : $$ \prod_{i=K}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^i}$$

So the coefficient of $x^N$ is the number of partitions of $N$  such that the smallest number in each partition is not less than $K$.